# Jersey Rest Client with empty string param

Tags: jersey, string

I'm using Jersey to consume some rest services, but I having a problem when I try to sent a parameter empty because seems that Jersey doesn't map the empty or null parameter.

Jersey generate something like (value is the empty string, the equals is lost and I get a 500 error):
    http://myservice.test.com/services/rest/setAttribute?id=555&value&test=test

If I go to the browser an enter (this one works!!!):
    http://myservice.test.com/services/rest/setAttribute?id=555&value=&test=test

The value field is required so I need to sent it every request, but I cannot set it in empty and sometimes I need the value an empty string.

Thanks...

Comment: This is a bug in Jersey client lib.  
Please check the ticket = http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1341

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@JsonWriteNullProperties` to the class you serializes to force it to write null values.